# Having trouble using XSLT to parse a simple XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, formatting

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ps">
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <div id="reports">

            <xsl:call-template name="report">
                <xsl:with-param name="report" select="." />
                <xsl:with-param name="heading">Today</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="report">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="4">
            <thead>
                <tr class="subheads">
                    <td>IP</td>
                    <td>Hits</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:for-each select="$report/ps:Objs/ps:Obj/ps:Props">
                    <xsl:sort select="Hits" order="descending" data-type="number" />
                    <tr>
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <!-- Even rows get the alt-row  class -->
                                <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 =  0">alt row</xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:if test="Hits &gt; 1000"> alert</xsl:if>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="ps:S[@N='Name']"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="ps:I32[@N='Count']"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML file: http://pastebin.com/Nzq6bC9b

(I have not included the XML directly because I can not seem to get it to format legibly)

I have been asked to assist making a XSLT document correctly pull info from an XML file and create a table with the data. I have no prior experience with XSLT and have searched quite a bit trying to accomplish my task. I have seen many examples, but I can not find any that show how to pull from a file formatted like mine. If someone could assist me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your XML file here, along with the expected result. Also make sure to show **complete** and **well-formed** documents, even if minimized - see: [mcve]. -- **Hint 1**: you have only named templates, which are never called. **Hint 2**: your XML has a default *namespace*. And there is nothing "strange" about it.

Comment: You might find the XML file strange, but it looks perfectly normal to me. That suggests there is something about it that you haven't encountered before, but the rest of us have no way of knowing what that might be. What's strange to you isn't necessarily strange to others.

Answer (score 0):

First thinks first, please provide complete and well-formed documents like [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like michael.hor257k and Michael Kay mentioned already before.

XML-File linked via Pastebin is wrong, cause the root-element `objs` is not closed.

Change your named template to following:

```
<xsl:template name="report">
    <xsl:param name="report"/>
    <xsl:param name="heading"/>
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

**Result**

```
<div id="reports">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="4">
        <thead>
            <tr class="subheads">
                <td>IP</td>
                <td>Hits</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="">
                <td>"16.249.75.135,</td>
                <td>87319</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alt row">
                <td>"26.249.91.195,</td>
                <td>22510</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="">
                <td>"16.249.69.8,</td>
                <td>6370</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="alt row">
                <td>"68.181.230.228,</td>
                <td>3818</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```